# How can I get colorbox to look like example 3 Colorbox?

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, css, colorbox

So I am using Node.js to run colorbox. I've gotten colorbox to work, however, color box doesn't look like the 3rd example, and I've used the same code and used the same images. Is there another configuration that I am missing?

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example3/

I've linked to colorbox.css, then jquery.js, then jquery.colorbox.js in that order. I've also added this script tag that the top of my page, under my css & javascript links.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gallery-link").colorbox({rel:'group2', transition:"fade"});
});
```

My links look like this:

```
<a class="gallery-link cboxElement" href="img/all/DWP0092.jpg">Link</a>
```

In my css file, I did change the location of the images in the example to

img/cbox/loading.gif
img/cbox/controls.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actually figured this out, the examples you download contain the wrong files and the html/css actually link to example files on the main website. So I used code inspector to download the images and css used in the example and it worked.